# Does JVM call default Constructor of Anonymous Class to create instance?

Tags: java

Does `JVM` call default `Constructor` of `Anonymous Class` to create instance.

My understanding may be stupid for that. I think, even if `Reflection API` is used to create an instance, there will be at least `Default Constructor`. `Anonymous Class` have a `Default Constructor`? Otherwise, how `JVM` or whatever create instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. You can even use other constructors through specifying parameters:

Given

```
public abstract class A {
   String str;
   public A(String str){
       this.str=str;
   }
   public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

You can do

```
...


A a = new A("Hello World") {
   public void doSomething() {
       System.out.println(str);
   }
};
a.doSomething();
```

When a class doesn't have an explicit constructor, it has an implicit default empty constructor. That is called, just as any other constructor would be called.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my question is not `How to use it?` It is  `How to create instance?`

Comment: @CycDemo I just created an instance in the answer. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, sorry if my English parser is not fault tolerant enough. I'll update the answer

Comment: If so, it is sure `abstract class` cannot create instance because of it does not have `Default Constructor`. So, where is `Constructor` to create instance in your code?

Comment: :) your comment and my comment will be parallel writing. I did not see your second comment.

Comment: @CycDemo The abstract class does have a constructor, but it can not be instantiated because it is abstract. This can be imagined as if all the constructors of the parent class would be in the anonymous class unchanged, or if you prefer that approach, having a single call to `super(<all the arguments>)`

Comment: Note, you can add an instance initialiser (and initialiser expressions on fields).

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that unlike normal classes, anonymous classes has different behaviour associated with implicit constructors.

When you define a normal class, compiler can implicitly insert only a no-arg constructor.
But with anonymous class you can get (implicitly by a compiler) all the constructors the superclass has.

Say we have a class:

```
class A {
    A(int i) {}
    A(String s) {}
}
```

If we subclass it as follows...

```
class B extends A {}
```

...we get a compilation error because compiler tries to do this:

```
class B extends A {
    B() {
        super();        // Error: there's no no-arg superclass constructor!
    }
}
```

But when we create an anonymous class it implicitly creates constructors as defined for a superclass (A)

```
A a1 = new A(1) {};     // OK. Uses (int) constructor
A a2 = new A("") {};    // OK. Uses (String) constructor
A a3 = new A() {};      // Error. There's no no-arg constructor
```

As if our anonymous class has these constructors

```
X(int i) {
    super(i);
}

X(String s) {
    super(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous classes have a default no args constructor that is called once by the JVM. Since an anonymous class has no name, it is not possible to define a constructor for an anonymous class. If your class requires a constructor, you must use a local class instead.

Comment: I disagree, but I might be at a fault here. Look at my example, there is an anonymous class, that extends the abstract class `A`, which has an explicit constructor having a `String` argument... Though it is true that you can not have different constructors than what the original class had.

Comment: The superclass has a constructor but the anonymous class itself doesn't.  Any arguments you specify between the parentheses following the superclass name in an anonymous class definition are implicitly passed to the superclass constructor.

Comment: I wonder what I will find by examining the `.getClass()` of the anonymous class I created in my example.. It will take some time though.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, a constructor is called to initialize newly created object. Anonymous class has default constructor, which initialize the fields of the class, if any, and calls constructor of the superclass.

Comment: I heard that there is no `Constructor` in `Anonymous Class`. But, my thinking is complex.

Comment: on JVM level, a constructor required to instantiate a class. You cannot declare constructor explicitly in an anonymous class just because the class' name is not available, but constructor is created and you can write statements which will go into the constructor using a block `{...}` inside the class.